# Calculate $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\sum\limits^n_{k=0} \binom n k(-\frac 1 3)^k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Is there a way to calculate $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\sum\limits^n_{k=0} \binom n k(-\frac 1 3)^k$?

If I would be able to calculate it I could find the solution at another task. So hopefully it is possible. I feel like I am missing out onto something here. Is ther a way to simplify the second part?

Comment: Doesn't the inner sum remind you of the binomial theorem?

Comment: The answer is equal to the number of licks it takes to get to the tootsie roll center of a tootsie pop.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-2/3}=3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\sum\limits^n_{k=0} \binom n k\left(-\frac 1 3\right)^k&=\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\sum\limits^n_{k=0} \binom n k 1^{n-k}\left(-\frac 1 3\right)^k\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac13\right)^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac23\right)^n \\
&= \frac{1}{1-\frac23} \\
&=3\end{align}

Comment: Why is $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\sum\limits^n_{k=0} \binom n k 1^{n-k}\left(-\frac 1 3\right)^k\ =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac13\right)^n \\$?

Comment: Binomal theorem, $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k a^{n-k} b^k$

Comment: Okay that makes sense. However I still don't understand the $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac23\right)^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac23} $ part. (Sorry... I really feel stupid now.)

Comment: It's a geometric series with common ratio of $\frac{2}{3}<1$.

Answer (score 0):

First multiply  by  $1^{n-k}$ $$\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\sum\limits^n_{k=0} \binom n k(-\frac 1 3)^k\\
\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\sum\limits^n_{k=0} \binom n k(-\frac 1 3)^k1^{n-k}\\
\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\sum\limits^n_{k=0} (1+\frac{-1}{3})^n\\
\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0} (\frac{+2}{3})^n=\\
\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}((\frac{+2}{3})^0+(\frac{+2}{3})^1+(\frac{+2}{3})^3+...+(\frac{+2}{3})^n+...)=\\\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1(1-(\frac23)^{n+1})}{1-\frac23}\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk (-r)^k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \color{blue}{(1-r)^k}
=\frac 1{1-(1-r)}=\frac 1r$$

Putting $r=\frac 13$ gives
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \left(-\frac 13\right)^k=\color{red}3$$